# Eloquent passing arguments not recognized by eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm working fixing a project and I made a scope in a model to query a relationship which also executes a closure:

This is the scope, it's a hotel:

```
public function scopeIsHotelAvailable($query, $start_date, $end_date){

        return $query->whereHas('isAvailableInRanges', function($q) use ($start_date, $end_date) {
                    $q->isAvailableInRanges($start_date, $end_date);
            });
    }
```

When I even attempt at running this I get the following error:

```
$hotel->ishotelavailable($start, $end);

TypeError: Too few arguments to function Modules/Hotel/Models/Hotel::isAvailableInRanges(), 0 passed in /home/ffuentes/pk2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/QueriesRelationships.php on line 475 and exactly 2 expected
```

I've seen this before but I don't know how to make Eloquent recognize the arguments.

EDIT:

This is the method being called from the closure which is part of the model Hotel.

```
public function isAvailableInRanges($start_date,$end_date){

        $days = max(1,floor((strtotime($end_date) - strtotime($start_date)) / DAY_IN_SECONDS));

        if($this->default_state)
        {
            $notAvailableDates = $this->hotelDateClass::query()->where([
                ['start_date','>=',$start_date],
                ['end_date','<=',$end_date],
                ['active','0']
            ])->count('id');
            if($notAvailableDates) return false;

        }else{
            $availableDates = $this->hotelDateClass::query()->where([
                ['start_date','>=',$start_date],
                ['end_date','<=',$end_date],
                ['active','=',1]
            ])->count('id');
            if($availableDates <= $days) return false;
        }

        // Check Order
        $bookingInRanges = $this->bookingClass::getAcceptedBookingQuery($this->id,$this->type)->where([
            ['end_date','>=',$start_date],
            ['start_date','<=',$end_date],
        ])->count('id');

        if($bookingInRanges){
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

The point of all this is to test the query results against these results and filter them. Back then when I begun trying it I just filtered the collection but it didn't work because the collection returned didn't include pagination and the eloquent elements it usually carries within itself.

Comment: `dd($start, $end)`

Comment: I deleted it. I was debugging but that's not the error

Comment: the problem is the relationship. you are using the wrong relationship...

Comment: alright but what's the issue with that relationship?

Comment: what's the relationship to this Hotel?

Comment: I'm testing the results against the relationship. I'll edit the post with the method.

Comment: It's edited now

Comment: many problems with these code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Problems 1:

You're using a scope method instead of relationship, try to use relationship method in [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence), like:

```php
->whereHas('yourRelationshipMethod', function($q) {...});
```

#### Problem 2:

The `isAvailableInRanges` is in Hotel model, so you can call it by Hotel, not relationship model.

#### Problem 3:

But the `isAvailableInRanges` is a instance method, so you cannot just call it by Eloquent builder, you need to get the instance and call this method:

```php
Hotel::first()->isAvailableInRanges($start_date,$end_date);
```

Comment: How can I rewrite the query or methods so that I can retrieve the query filtered? I wouldn't want to retrieve them one by one. Can I get () them? And the pagination is lost!

Comment: Not really know your relationship and another class, hard to make the query.